# Success URL for Payflow Link Pro in Magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1, paypal-payflow-pro

I have configured PayPal flow Link Pro, It's working fine but success page is not coming. I found for success page we need to configure success URL in payment side. Is that below success URL is correct or not? If any other success URL we need to set means please tell...Thanks in advance...

```
Base_URL/checkout/onepage/success/
```

[image: Return URL]

Answer (score 0):

You need to change you paypal payflow account setting as per below

**admin > Service Settings > Set Up > make all method get to post**